# Linux - сервер для сайта

Tags: linux, apache, сервер

Начал изучать сети и все подобное. Решил развернуть сервер для домашнего использования из старого ПК - все получилось.

Но вот вопрос: возможно ли получить доступ к моим данным (`/var/www/html/*`) из интернета, написав в адресной строке браузера "IP" моей машины? Так же прошу расписать если можно.

Comment: Если у вас реальный IP и порт не закрыт фаерволом - то можно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас должен быть статичный (выделенный) IP от провайдера, который принадлежит только вам. Если динамический и используется не только вами, но и другими пользователями сети, то сразу ничего не получится.

Далее, если вы подключены через роутер, и роутер раздает интернет, надо на ваш статичный IP пробросить порт и связать его с локальной машиной, через NAT и настроить права доступа на самой локальной машине.

Если подключение к сети осуществляется непосредственно на компьютере (устанавливается подключение с интернетом), то необходимо просто разрешить доступ через firewall.

Далее нужно чтобы ваш Apache был настроен на внешний интерфейс сетевой карты, а не на внутренний и все будет работать.

Если хотите развернуть сайт, то не надо этого делать на локальной машине, купите хостинг и получите больше выгоды от его использования.

Comment: На счет динамического ip вы не совсем правы. теоретически так работать можно. но оно конечно не особо стабильно. необходимо использовать внешние системы dyndns и обращение по имени

Comment: @Mike Да, это так :) Но вопрос пользователя стоял в том, чтобы вводить именно свой IP в строку браузера, а не внешние адреса и я ответил что ничего не получится насчет именно этой возможности :)

Comment: @Mike, как DynDNS поможет при "сером" (невидимом из интернета) адресе пользователя?

Comment: @Arhad Я говорил про реальный (белый) динамический IP